# Load outerjoin results in sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to load the results in this structure:

```json
{

    addresses: [,…]
    birth_date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
    created_at: "2020-09-29T15:27:30.789498"
    disabled: false
    email: "sami@email.me"
    email_confirmed: false
    gender: "m"
    id: 11
    items: [,…]
    mobile: 80080080
    mobile_confirmed: true
    name_first: "Sami"
    name_last: "xx"
    newsletter: true
    orders: [,…]
    preferred_language: "ar"
    updated_at: "2020-11-13T15:21:57.301272"
    
}
```

But I am getting empty `orders` and `items`. Their columns are not loaded.

```py
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id =                  Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name_first =          Column(String, nullable=False)
    name_last =           Column(String, nullable=True)
    mobile =              Column(Integer, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    mobile_otp=           Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    mobile_confirmed =    Column(Boolean, default=False)
    email =               Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    email_confirmed =     Column(Boolean, default=False)
    password =            Column(String, nullable=False)
    password_reset_otp =  Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    gender=               Column(String, nullable=False)
    birth_date=           Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    preferred_language =  Column(String, nullable=False)
    newsletter =          Column(Boolean, default=False)
    disabled =            Column(Boolean, default=False)
    created_at=           Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    updated_at=           Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    addresses = relationship('Addresses', uselist=True, back_populates="user", lazy='noload')
    orders = relationship('Orders', uselist=True, backref=backref("user"), lazy='noload')
    items = relationship('Items', uselist=True, backref=backref("user"), lazy='noload')
    staff = relationship("Staff", uselist=False, back_populates="user", lazy='raise')


class Orders(Base):
    __tablename__="orders"
    id=             Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id=        Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    address_id=     Column(Integer, ForeignKey('addresses.id'))

    delivery_at=    Column(DateTime)
    staff_id=      Column(Integer, ForeignKey('staff.id'), nullable=True)
    store_id=      Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stores.id'), nullable=True)

    created_at=     Column(DateTime)
    updated_at=     Column(DateTime)
    active    =     Column(Boolean, default=True)

    items = relationship("Items", uselist=True, back_populates="order", lazy='raise')
    lifecycle = relationship("OrderLifeCycles")
    
class Items(Base):
    __tablename__="items"
    id=             Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id=        Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    order_id =      Column(Integer, ForeignKey('orders.id'), nullable=True)
    size_id  =      Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sizes.id'))
    price    =      Column(Float, nullable=True)
    qty      =      Column(Integer)

    order= relationship("Orders", uselist=False, back_populates="items", lazy='raise')
    size= relationship("Sizes", uselist=False, lazy='raise')
```

SQLAlchemy query:

```py
def get_user_by_mobile(db: Session, mobile: str, items: bool, orders:bool):
    orders = db.query(tables.Orders).filter(tables.Orders.active==True).subquery("orders")
    items = db.query(tables.Items).options(joinedload(tables.Items.size).joinedload(tables.Sizes.product)).filter(tables.Items.order_id==None).subquery("items")
    query = db.query(tables.Users).outerjoin(items, tables.Users.id == items.c.user_id).outerjoin(orders, tables.Users.id == orders.c.user_id)

    query = query.options(joinedload(tables.Users.addresses)).filter(tables.Users.mobile == mobile)

    return query.first()
```

How to load the subquery result lists as an attribute in the json structure example at the top? similar to the way addresses get loaded.

The column names of the subqueries are not included in the query statement:

```sql
SELECT          users.id                           AS users_id, 
                users.name_first                   AS users_name_first, 
                users.name_last                    AS users_name_last, 
                users.mobile                       AS users_mobile, 
                users.mobile_otp                   AS users_mobile_otp, 
                users.mobile_confirmed             AS users_mobile_confirmed, 
                users.email                        AS users_email, 
                users.email_confirmed              AS users_email_confirmed, 
                users.password                     AS users_password, 
                users.password_reset_otp           AS users_password_reset_otp, 
                users.gender                       AS users_gender, 
                users.birth_date                   AS users_birth_date, 
                users.preferred_language           AS users_preferred_language, 
                users.newsletter                   AS users_newsletter, 
                users.disabled                     AS users_disabled, 
                users.created_at                   AS users_created_at, 
                users.updated_at                   AS users_updated_at, 
                addresses_1.id                     AS addresses_1_id, 
                addresses_1.label                  AS addresses_1_label, 
                St_asewkb(addresses_1.coordinates) AS addresses_1_coordinates, 
                addresses_1.building_number        AS addresses_1_building_number, 
                addresses_1.flat_number            AS addresses_1_flat_number, 
                addresses_1.disabled               AS addresses_1_disabled, 
                addresses_1.created_at             AS addresses_1_created_at, 
                addresses_1.updated_at             AS addresses_1_updated_at, 
                addresses_1.user_id                AS addresses_1_user_id 
FROM            users 
left outer join 
                ( 
                       SELECT items.id       AS id, 
                              items.user_id  AS user_id, 
                              items.order_id AS order_id, 
                              items.size_id  AS size_id, 
                              items.price    AS price, 
                              items.qty      AS qty 
                       FROM   items 
                       WHERE  items.order_id IS NULL) AS anon_1 
ON              users.id = anon_1.user_id 
left outer join 
                ( 
                       SELECT orders.id          AS id, 
                              orders.user_id     AS user_id, 
                              orders.address_id  AS address_id, 
                              orders.delivery_at AS delivery_at, 
                              orders.staff_id    AS staff_id, 
                              orders.store_id    AS store_id, 
                              orders.created_at  AS created_at, 
                              orders.updated_at  AS updated_at, 
                              orders.active      AS active 
                       FROM   orders 
                       WHERE  orders.active = TRUE) AS anon_2 
ON              users.id = anon_2.user_id 
left outer join addresses AS addresses_1 
ON              users.id = addresses_1.user_id 
WHERE           users.mobile = %(mobile_1)s
```

Comment: Check the values of [lazy=](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/docs_preview/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy) that you are using. They don't appear to be appropriate for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GordThompson That does not affect the results. I use `lazy='raise'` to avoid emitting another select statement. Instead I have to explicitly load relationships during querying using `joinedload` etc